# How to fix no assistant results in Xcode+ Assistant layout is horizontal & not vertical

Tags: xcode

I have tried to restart Xcode and even made edits. I tried the previous solutions but nothing works. Also, when the assistant layout opens, The assistant(where the code should ideally be) falls beneath my storyboard and not beside it.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can make the assistant fall beside your storyboard: Click on the linked-circles icon (what you may have previously clicked on to open the assistant), go to layout and choose "Assistant on Right".

[image]